# Welcome message Microsoft Bot Framework

Tags: c#, azure, botframework

I'm attempting to have a welcome message displayed on MS Bot App, hosted on Azure accessed from the company SharePoint by embedding a link.

I've been having little success in doing so.

I've reviewed [this solution](http://www.davidezordan.net/blog/?p=8119), and many others similar, and they don't work in my case.

If I understand the code correctly, the user in the the `IConversationUpdateActivity` object (a user profile on Skype\Facebook or whatever) drives the functionality. Is that correct?

As I intend for the bot to be accessed through a link in an iframe on the company's intranet, I'm not sure that this would be suitable.

How might I achieve this? Is it possible? I understand the bot framework is open source, can it be done this way? How if so?

Answer (score 0):

> the user in the the IConversationUpdateActivity object (a user profile on Skype\Facebook or whatever) drives the functionality.

It seems that you reviewed [this solution](http://www.davidezordan.net/blog/?p=8119) and implemented displaying welcome message in `ConversationUpdate`, and it should work fine with emulator. As you mentioned, user with different channels drives the functionality, in this [SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42943665/how-to-display-a-welcome-message-from-my-bot-using-microsoft-bot-framework), we can find that the solution (same as you reviewed) does not work in Skype or Facebook Messenger.

> I intend for the bot to be accessed through a link in an iframe on the company's intranet, I'm not sure that this would be suitable.

[This github sample](https://github.com/FranckyC/PnP/tree/feature/starter-intranet-v1.3/Solutions/Business.StarterIntranet#configure-the-qna-bot) demonstrates the integration with an Azure bot, if you’d like to integrate bot with SharePoint application,  you can refer to it and try to use the Direct Line channel to enable your SharePoint application to communicate with your bot.

Comment: thank you, but this doesn't really address my question. Can you tell me if there's a way to have a welcome message display when accessing through the iframe without using a Windows or other app credential?