# How to set greeting message in Microsoft Chatbot service

Tags: azure, chatbot, azure-bot-service

I want to set greeting meesage for my chatbot on Microsoft Bot service. I have already integrated chatbot to Microsoft Team. There is a documentation for setting greeting message but I do not understand where can I find all these files. Anyone can help me with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a great question already covering this here [How to display a welcome message from my Bot using Microsoft Bot Framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42943665/how-to-display-a-welcome-message-from-my-bot-using-microsoft-bot-framework)

Let me know if you need any more help!

Comment: Well, when I try to paste this code to MessagesController.cs into Activity HandleSystemMessage, it does not work. It shows me an error when I try to build the app. `else if (message.Type == ActivityTypes.ContactRelationUpdate)
{
    if(message.Action == "add")
    {
        var reply = message.CreateReply("WELCOME!!!");
        ConnectorClient connector = new ConnectorClient(new Uri(message.ServiceUrl));
        await connector.Conversations.ReplyToActivityAsync(reply);
    }
}`